# Column-Based Grid with Cells of equal hight

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table-like layout which needs to be responsive . The problem i'm having is that the columns need to be the same width as the screen on mobile devices and displayed side-by-side on a tablet or normal screen.

I decided that this may be impossible with a normal table, that is cells wrapped by a row. So i've build my table column-based, that is cells wrapped by a column (custom divs) ([see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODjHP.png)).

It works fine, columns on small screens are width:100%, and on bigger screens width: 12.5% (as there are 8 of them), both floated to the left side.

Now here is the problem: every cell within a row must be the same height (ex. every first cell in a column must be as high as the biggest one of them). (not important on the mobile view, only on desktop and tablet)

My questions are: 
 1. is there a way to do this in css
 2. or what is a good way to do this in jquery

My jquery approach was this litte jquery-script ([jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eb46hvy0/)):

```
    var column = $(".column");
    var count = column.eq(0).children().length;

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
        var max_height = 0;
        for(var j = 0; j < column.length; j++){
            var height = column.eq(j).children().eq(i).height();
            if(height > max_height){
                max_height = height;
            }
        }
        for(var j = 0; j < column.length; j++){
            column.eq(j).children().eq(i).height(max_height);
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way then iterating over each row searching the biggest element and then setting each cell in the row to that maximum height?

Comment: Both flexbox and grid layout in CSS can do this probably without too much convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` with `flex-wrap: wrap;` here.

```
.column {
    width: 12.5%;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column .cell {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFF;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.column .cell span {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/taxL1ugw/1/

EDIT: For column based layouts, its quite tricky. I've not found a way of getting flexbox to work there without hard coding in heights, which defeats the whole point.

---

CSS Tables should work, although this is untested:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      row 1 col 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell hide-on-small">
      row 1 col 2
    </div>
    <div class="cell hide-on-small">
      row 1 col 3<br/>with more content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      row 2 col 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell hide-on-small">
      row 2 col 2
    </div>
    <div class="cell hide-on-small">
      row 2 col 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      row 3 col 1<br/>with more content
    </div>
    <div class="cell hide-on-small">
      row 3 col 2
    </div>
    <div class="cell hide-on-small">
      row 3 col 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .table { display: table; }
    .row { display: table-row; }
    .cell { display: table-cell; }
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hide-on-small {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Agree with fredrivett, but be careful, not all browsers support it the same way, so you may run into some issues.

Comment: Good point @stevelacerda7. I'd advise using something like [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to handle this if you can.

Comment: while implementing into my project i noticed that there are 2 cells of a column side by side. i need them to say under each other.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. The cells wrap from first to last, 2 per line. This is normal behaviour:

[1][2]
[3][4]

Is that not the layout you want? Note I realise I linked to the wrong jsfiddle before, I've updated the answer to fix the link to the right jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't want them to wrap. I just want all cells labelled with "a" to be the same height, all cells with "b" the same height and so on (see the image in my post)... also all cells in a column should stay under each other.

Comment: @nicobach Ah I see. The only option I can think of here that doesn't need hardcoded magic numbers is CSS tables. I've updated my answer to show the basics of how that might work, but its a bit fiddly.